# How to animate the sorting of a ListView in Android?

Tags: android, listview, sorting, animation

I have an unsorted Integer ListView.I want to sort this list in ascending order of integers when i click a button.Also i want to animate the sorting.I want to see the items being animated while sorting and added back to Listview.I have a method for sorting the integers. I don't know how to call this animation without selecting any view because i want to do the sort on a button click.I am confused about how to get the position of item.
Somebody please help me with this.Thanks in advance.

Sorting method:

```
  public static void swap(List<Integer> sort, int i, int j) {
        int tmp = sort.get(i);
        sort.set(i, sort.get(j));
        sort.set(j, tmp);

  }

  public static void doSort(List<Integer> sort) {
        int min;
        for (int i = 0; i < sort.size(); ++i) {
            //find minimum in the rest of array
            min = i;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < sort.size(); ++j) {
                if (sort.get(j) < sort.get(min)) {
                    min = j;
                }
            }

            //do swap
            swap(sort, i, min);

        }
  }
```

I used this for animation:

```
 animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
            R.anim.slide_up_left);
    animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            doSort(myList);
            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Sorting is done in background. And then the sorted list is displayed.

Comment: Basically what you want is to show animation on button click (where you want the listitem to move to its new position as an animation). It can't be done straight up. Try overriding this [library](https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview) and see if it works for you. Demo of this library is at playstore. [Click here to see](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobeta.android.demodslv)

Comment: @Nevaeh did you got it?